# Как добавить wsse:Security header (SOAP)

Tags: c#, soap, header

Есть веб-сервис. На C# пишу программу, которая подключается и тащит данные. Для того чтобы подключиться, надо пройти авторизацию. Пробовал через WSE3.0, но для CRM этот вариант не подходит. Собственно вот такой конверт должен быть.

```
POST http://wsservice:8980/crmws/crmws HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 1074
Host: smr01-app02:8980
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_102)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sup="http://support.diasoft.ru">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-DAFFC35F833AA27EE214919177923171"><wsse:Username>ws-user</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">p@ssw0rd</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">E6lB35rE2Ijk+HtjeIhPwg==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2017-04-11T13:36:32.316Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sup:DSLegalFindByIDReq>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <sup:LegalID>?</sup:LegalID>
      </sup:DSLegalFindByIDReq>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Пробовал сделать вот таким методом, но пока не соображу как туда подставить UserToken, Password.

```
using (var client = new WSPORTTYPEClient())
            using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
            {
                MessageHeader usernameToken = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UsernameToken",
                    "http://wsservice:8980/crmws/crmws", "ws-user");
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(usernameToken);

                MessageHeader passwordTextHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("PasswordText",
                    "http://wsservice:8980/crmws/crmws", "p@ssw0rd");
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(passwordTextHeader);

                MessageHeader sessionTypeHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("SessionType",
                    "http://smr1-app02:8980/crmws/crmwshttp://wsservice:8980/crmws/crmws", "None");
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(sessionTypeHeader);



                DSLegalFindByIDReq req = new DSLegalFindByIDReq();

                req.LegalID = 234234234234;
                req.LegalIDSpecified = true;

                DSLegalFindByIDRes res = new DSLegalFindByIDRes();

                res = client.dsLegalFindByID(req);

                Console.WriteLine(res);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать биндинг, имеющий настройки безопасности. Возможно, придется собрать кастомный биндинг. Вот пример с чего начинать ковырять:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding>
          <security allowInsecureTransport="true" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
          <textMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Аналогично можно и программно биндинг собрать, если вынесение его в конфиг не нравится.

Логин и пароль надо записывать в `client.ClientCredentials.Username`:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ...;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ...;
```

Comment: А биндинг где делается? Я нашел одну статью, в которой об этом говорится, но я так и не понял где это делать. Т.е. у меня сейчас есть проект Windows Form, подключен Service Reference WSDL. Везде пишут про web.config...

Comment: вот код самого подключения к веб-сервису: WSPORTTYPEClient client = new WSPORTTYPEClient();


            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName="...";    
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password="...";    
            DSLegalFindByIDReq req = new DSLegalFindByIDReq();

            req.LegalID = 3123124325;
            req.LegalIDSpecified = true;

            DSLegalFindByIDRes res = new DSLegalFindByIDRes();

            res = client.dsLegalFindByID(req);

Comment: Но на шаге res = client.dsLegalFindByID(req); выдает ошибку, что запрос не авторизован.

Comment: @AndreySherman неужели у вашей программы нет конфига? Не верю. Его ж студия сама создает при добавлении service reference.

Comment: При добавлении service reference создаются configuration.svcinfo, configuration91.svcingo, crmws.wsdl, reference.svcmap

Comment: @AndreySherman не верю

Comment: Если речь идет об web.config, то его нет, а вот app.config есть в проекте.

Comment: @AndreySherman поздравляю, вот вы и нашли конфиг к своей программе!